# Union on Dynamic (Loop) SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, while-loop, union, dynamic-sql

with the below loop script, I am creating tables for every period. What I need is that I would like to **union all** these multiple tables into one single table within the same script. Can anyone help me do that?

```
DECLARE @Interval_List as TABLE (index_1 int, Interval VARCHAR(50), Interval_2 VARCHAR(50), From_date date, To_date date)
INSERT INTO @Interval_List VALUES (1,  '2021_Q3',          '2021 Q3',        '2021-07-01', '2021-09-30')
INSERT INTO @Interval_List VALUES (2,  '2021_Q4',          '2021 Q4',        '2021-10-01', '2021-12-31')
INSERT INTO @Interval_List VALUES (3,  '2021_H2',          '2021 H2',        '2021-07-01', '2021-12-31')
INSERT INTO @Interval_List VALUES (4,  '2021',             '2021',           '2021-07-01', '2021-12-31')

DECLARE @StartDate AS DATE
DECLARE @EndDate AS DATE
DECLARE @CurrentDate AS DATE
DECLARE @index_first int
declare @index_last int
declare @interval VARCHAR(50)
declare @interval_2 VARCHAR(50)
declare @issue_table nvarchar(max)
declare @service_table nvarchar(max)

SELECT @index_first = min(index_1),  @index_last = max(index_1) FROM @Interval_List

SET @CurrentDate = @StartDate
SET @issue_table = 'dbo.table1'
SET @service_table = 'dbo.table2'

WHILE (@index_first <= @index_last)
BEGIN

SELECT @StartDate = From_date,  @EndDate = To_date, @interval = Interval, @interval_2 = Interval_2 FROM @Interval_List where index_1 = @index_first

IF OBJECT_ID(@issue_table) IS NULL
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Bad object!', 11, 1);
    RETURN;
END

declare @query nvarchar(max);

set @query = 
N'

SELECT 
A.SERVICE,
A.Service_Group,
A.Portfolio,
Interval,
SUM(Metric_1_Dividend_C_New) AS Metric_1_Dividend_C_New
'
+ N'into dbo.METRIC_1_' + @interval

+
N'
FROM
(
SELECT 
ISSUE_CREATION_DATE,
ISSUE_ID,
SERVICE,
SERVICE_GROUP,
PORTFOLIO,
@Interval_2 as Interval,
AVG(Metric_No_1_Dividend) AS Metric_1_Dividend_C_New
'
+ N' from ' + @issue_table +
N' where PROJECT IS NOT NULL
AND cast(FORMAT(ISSUE_CREATION_DATE, ''yyyyMMdd'') as varchar(30)) >= cast(FORMAT(@StartDate, ''yyyyMMdd'') as varchar(30)) 
AND cast(FORMAT(ISSUE_CREATION_DATE, ''yyyyMMdd'') as varchar(30)) <= cast(FORMAT(@EndDate, ''yyyyMMdd'') as varchar(30))
GROUP BY ISSUE_CREATION_DATE, ISSUE_ID,SERVICE,SERVICE_GROUP,PORTFOLIO
) A
GROUP BY SERVICE,Service_Group,Portfolio,Interval 

'
exec sys.sp_executesql @query,
    N'@StartDate date, @EndDate date, @Interval_2 VARCHAR(50)',
    @StartDate, @EndDate, @Interval_2;

SET @index_first = @index_first + 1;
END
;
```

Comment: What you need is to *not* use a script to UNION multiple tables like this. All supported SQL Server versions and editions support table partitioning which means you don't even need separate tables per period. Besides, partitioning like are needed when you have to manage multiple million rows per period. You get no perf benefit from manual partitioning. To improve performance you need proper indexes, especially on the date column and possibly (depending on the query types) columnstore indexes to speed up aggregate queries

Comment: If you can't use table partitioning (why?) a *view* that combines all tables with `UNION ALL` will work far better. Your script is actually rebuilding that view every time. This could even improve performance if the underlying tables have constraints on the date column that tell the query optimizer what values are stored in each table, thus eliminating tables from any query automatically. The same works in table partitioning

Comment: On the other hand, `cast(FORMAT(ISSUE_CREATION_DATE, ''yyyyMMdd'')` will kill performance and force a scan of *all* rows in *all* tables even if you want to find a single row for a single date. It's quite possible that you don't even need multiple tables, just fixing the bad query. A 1M row table with indexes is small data these days. If `ISSUE_CREATION_DATE` is a `date` and indexed, a simple `ISSUE_CREATION_DATE between @StartDate and @EndDate` will have the best performance

Comment: PS: I didn't downvote but those that did are slightly justified. This script is guaranteed to have terrible performance. Looping and partitioning try to cover up the problem but make it far worse instead.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you very much for valuable comments. Actually, my original script is not that basic, I have some other left join tables as well for every period. Just for clarification I pasted a little bit of my original script. So, I still need to union the tables created within this loop.

Comment: For cast(FORMAT(ISSUE_CREATION_DATE, ''yyyyMMdd'')  part of the script, I appreciate your comment as I did not know this function has such bad impact on performance. I has replaced this function with between operator and the performance has been much more better. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `my original script is not that basic,` more reason to *avoid* dynamic SQL and loops. A VIEW with properly indexed tables and constraints acts almost like a single table, so whatever the script does with all those tables would be simpler if there was only one thing to query. A single table partitioned by date would result in an even simpler script, and far easier and faster data modifications. A columnstore table would be even faster (100x), especially for such grouping queries and naturally partitioned in 1M-row buckets. It would also be 10x smaller, resulting in 1/10th the IO

Comment: Check [Columnstore indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-ver16), which available in all supported versions and editions. Notice that 1M rows is the minimum bucket size - the database will wait until it has 1M new rows before it creates a new bucket. Do your tables have more than 1M rows per quarter? Wouldn't your script be faster if it used a single fully indexed, automatically "partitioned" fact table?

Answer (score -1):

Before you continue, please make sure that you read about [table partitioning](https://www.sqlshack.com/database-table-partitioning-sql-server/) and [creating a view](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp) for your unions, because, intuitively the problem you describe sounds like these. If neither partitioning, nor views are good for you, then read the sections below:

## How can I get tables by name

```
SELECT [name]
FROM sys.tables
WHERE [name] LIKE '%somepattern%'
```

## How to generate a command:

```
SELECT CONCAT('INSERT INTO ', [name], '(col1, col2, col3) values(', value1, ', ', value2, ', ', value3, ')')
FROM sys.tables
WHERE [name] LIKE '%somepattern%'
```

## How to concatenate rows

You can use `STRING_AGG(yourstring, 'separator')`, like:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT('INSERT INTO ', [name], '(col1, col2, col3) values(', value1, ', ', value2, ', ', value3, ')'), ' UNION ')
FROM sys.tables
WHERE [name] LIKE '%somepattern%'
```

Comment: SQL Server does not have `GROUP_CONCAT` it has `STRING_AGG`. `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is for compatibility only, use `sys.tables` etc instead. You need to quote names with `QUOTENAME` otherwise you can get injection problems.

Comment: @Charlieface thanks for the feedback. Changed `GROUP_CONCAT` to `STRING_AGG`, I originally intended to write the latter, but since my current RDBMS is MySQL, I have written the former :). Changes reference from `information_schema.tables` to `sys.tables` and adjusted the commands (I have no SQL Server installed to test it, I hope the code is correct). I do not need to quote names with `QUOTENAME`, as in this case the names are `table` names and protection against injection is unnecessary, unless users are trusted with naming tables.

Comment: @Charlieface so, basically I applied 2 of the 3 suggestions you made as `QUOTENAME` in this context will be unnecessary unless the tables can be named by the users, assuming that the developers are not planning to hack themselves.

Comment: Injection is not just about security but also about correctness. A perfectly legitimate table might be called `User` or it might have a hyphen `-`. You should *always* use `QUOTENAME`